# Amplify Push Notification problem (React Native)

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

i'm using amplify to configurate push notification messages in react native, all is good but i need send notification to determinate devices, **not for all devices**.

I'm using:

- Aws Pinpoint (to send notification).
- Amplify (to recieve notifications)
- Mobile Hub (to configurate integration)

Index.js (Main project file)

```
...
import InformApp from './app/App';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger({ predicate: () => false });
const persistedReducer = persistReducer({ key: 'root', storage, blacklist: ['filter', 'modals'] }, reducers);

//AWS
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from './src/aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
...
```

App.js (Main View):

```
...
  componentDidMount() {
    // get the notification data when notification is received
    PushNotification.onNotification(notification => {
      // console.warn(notification)
      this.props.recieveNotification(notification._data.data.jsonBody);

      // required on iOS only (see fetchCompletionHandler docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html)
      if (PushNotificationIOS != undefined) {
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
      }
    });

    // get the registration token
    PushNotification.onRegister(token => {
      console.log("in app registration", token);
    });

    // get the notification data when notification is opened
    PushNotification.onNotificationOpened(notification => {
      alert(notification);
      // console.warn(notification);
      // console.warn("the notification is opened", notification);
    });
  }
...
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: I perform the following steps:

1. I have an application in vuejs that sends a request to the ** api gateway ** (of aws) with the message.
2. Api Gateway receives the request and sends it a lambda function.
3. This function sends via *pinpoint* (aws) the notification to the devices.
4. Devices notified notification with amplification and their push notification function.